How to exactly fit an image in a roundedImage for .SVG image?
I've been trying to make this work for quite some time and have no clue whatsoever. I'm trying to make an image having a little gradient border, and fit in a rounded box.
<svg viewBox="0 0 2400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="borderGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#5BCEFA; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="33%" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="66%" style="stop-color:#F5A9B8; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#5BCEFA; stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <clipPath id="roundedImage">
            <rect x="12" y="10" width="2373" height="380" rx="15" ry="15" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect x="8" y="7" width="2381" height="387" rx="15" ry="15" fill="none" stroke="url(#borderGradient)" stroke-width="10"/>
    <image href="C:\Users\...\banner.png" x="12" y="10" width="2373" height="380" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#roundedImage)" />
</svg>

This works well in my navigator, but when it comes to make an image object with that in my readme, I get a very very zoomed banner in my frame. Integrating using ;
<img src="./.../banner.svg" alt="banner" style="width: auto; height: auto;"/>
In navigator (good):

and in editor / on readme.md (bad):

Has anyone any clue why this happens ?
Tried to use preserveAspectRatio, but I'm not really sure this is the way to go.

Probably you are stretching a smaller image. What is the size of your image?  Is it width="2373" height="380"?

image is exactly 2400 by 400

Images need to be self contained. So you're most likely seeing the broken image placeholder

So in the end you need to convert your png to a base64 encoded data url so your image would look something like this <image href="data:image/webp;base64, ..." />. You can use pretty much any binary to base64 encoder as long as you prepend the suitable mime type. Have a look at my own helper (automatically adding mime types for common files like images or fonts). BTW you should probably rather put the outline rect in front of the image.

This question is similar to: Images in SVG Image tags not showing up in Chrome, but displays locally?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
